# using a custom javascript code in joomla

Tags: joomla

I've been asked to write a custom javascript to create a tooltip. I've done this and  the code works on my localhost and on my own online webhost but it refuses to work in joomla 2.5. I've heard this could be caused by the moo tools pluggin that comes with joomla itself? what plug in should I install to make my javascript work? I checked the code and it works all around. I apologize if this is an inappropriate question.

edit: The problem is it just won't run the code at all. it doesn't apply the CSS. which is loaded from another file, though it does apply the style for the rest of the site. When there's suppose to be a custom css for the `title` attribute in a `img` tag I just get a regular text window

Comment: I would suggest if you want some help you need to provide some error messages or code so that Joomla/MooTools people have something to actually provide feedback on...

Comment: Just a thought, and you may have already thought of this, but when I was starting out with Joomla, relative URLs would always mess with me -- how some things were relative to the base url, while others were relative to /templates/myTemplate, or /modules/myModule. Did you check to make sure your links to your includes are right? I'm guessing your CSS file isn't being loaded at all.

Comment: So where are you putting this custom JS code and how? are you inserting it directly into an article override or the template itself or...

Comment: @Dennis it does load the CSS. It just skips or reads over the part that is relevant to my script.

Comment: @cppl I'm putting the code directly in the template itself... the index.php file

Comment: @JeffreyKlinkhamer: Maybe there's a conflict in your CSS? Try adding !important; to the CSS attribute that's being 'skipped'. If it messes up the rest of the site, you have a conflict.

Comment: You can try to remove the mootools js include and see if it works...
And like @Dennis said you should work with $this->baseurl, otherwise can you provide us a link so we can troubleshoot the problem ?
btw, hope your joomla cache is off !